# Meaning of "Radio your way"

Tags: verbs, punctuation

The slogan of a German radio provider (they offer stations from all over the world) is:

> Radio your way

I think they mean it like the Burger King slogan

> Have it your way

which means customize it to suit your needs.

But, if they really mean it that way isn't there a comma missing?

> Radio, your way

Because without a comma I understand it like: I am on my way and I am constantly transmitting something (for example where I am going).

to radio sth. = to broadcast sth. on the radio

Please tell me if my thinking is completely off.

Comment: Yes, a comma, or a dash, would *conventionally* be used there to show that **your way** is a supplemental phrase modifying the noun **radio** and that **radio** is not a verb analogous to "fight your way (through a crowd)" or some other possible meaning, such as you said, "signal your current location".

Comment: I understand it as *make/fight your way in life with radio*.
I think it's not a matter of grammar or punctuation but instead of idioms and figures of speech.

Comment: @TRomano since you are a native speaker, I would consider that an answer :)

Comment: Off topic: is this question appropriate for this forum or would it suit "English language usage" better?

Comment: We have a **punctuation** tag so it's not off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Your way* here is an adjectival<sup>†</sup> modifying *radio*: it is postposed because it originated as a preposition phrase, *in your way* = "in the way you prefer", but the *in* has almost disappeared in contemporary English.

*Radio your way* is thus a nominal, equivalent to "Radio the way you like it".

*Your way* is a common advertising tag for food prepared to the customer's specifications ("steak your way", "pizza your way", "pasta your way") and for other customized goods and services ("luxury your way", "suits your way", "fitness your way").

---

<sup>†</sup> The construction *POSSESSIVE way* is typically used as an adverbial--Frank Sinatra's song *My Way*, with each stanza closing "I did it my way*, is an example--and it could be argued that *radio your way* implies "We produce radio your way* = "we produce it in the manner you prefer us to produce it"; but I think even in that paraphrase *your way* is better understood as an object complement, and thus an adjectival.

Comment: How can I know who to believe now? :(

Comment: I think @TRomano is speaking of formal use, where disambiguating nominal and verbal uses of *radio* would be desirable. But formal use is rarely a concern in advertising.

Comment: So, the slogan is so informal American English that a German misunderstands it? Poor advertising in Germany :(

Comment: Advertising often doesn't use standard grammar or usage if the advertiser thinks it sounds better a different way.